# C++ "return" without value

Tags: c++, return, return-value

What is the meaning if there is no value of return? Thanks

```
void run_algo() {
   ...
   project(tolabel->second);
   ...
}

void project(Projected &projected) {
    unsigned int sup = support(projected);
    if(sup < minsup) // minsup is a global variable
        return  ;
//-------------^--------->no expression here?    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please read a C++ book before asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: It returns from the function. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @SethCarnegie but then he might come to StackOverflow to ask what book to read...

Comment: @CashCow: In which case, he'll find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the type of your function is void, when you use `return`, it exits the function immediately and back to the caller.

Answer (score 8):

The function is declared as returning `void`. So there is no value returned. Using `return` in this function just means this function is finished.

Answer (score 3):

It just exits the function immediately, returning to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the execution of this function ends at this point, and it does not continue to the following lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to exit from the function immediately. It resolves the necessity of an `else` statement in this case.

```
void project(Projected &projected) {
    unsigned int sup = support(projected);
    if(sup < minsup) // minsup is a global variable
        ;
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jump out from current function without returning value.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement:
Terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function (or, in the case of the main function, transfers control back to the operating system). Execution resumes in the calling function at the point immediately following the call.

From msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k68ktdwf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx