# In C++, is "return;" the same thing as "return NULL;"?

Tags: c++, null, return

my question is `return;` the same as `return NULL;` in C++?

I understand that in C++, `return NULL;` is the same as `return 0;` in the context of pointers. Obviously for integers, this is not the case as NULL cannot be added, subtracted, etc. And that it is encouraged by some to use 0 instead of NULL for pointers because it is more convenient for portability. I'm curious if this is another instance where an equivalence occurs.

I suspect that they are equivalent because `return;` is saying return 'nothing' and NULL is 'nothing.' However, if someone can either confirm or deny this (with explanation, of course), I would be very grateful!

Comment: You seem to confuse a lot of things...

Comment: `NULL` is not 'nothing', it is a C macro that expands to something like `0` (but not necessarily) that is of pointer type and doesn't alias any valid pointers. The C++ equivalent is `nullptr`.

Comment: In particular, the null pointer is a valid value of a pointer type.

Comment: From the Null tag on the site: "Null means *nothing* or *unknown* (depending on context)."

Comment: NULL is not 'nothing' in C++. It's just a macro (defined in `<cstddef>`) that evaluates to number `0`. But afaik it's not a part of the language itself and it has no meaning in C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is `return;` the same as `return NULL;` in C++?

No.

`return` is used to "break" out from a function that has no return value, i.e. a return type of `void`.

`return NULL` returns the value `NULL`, and the return type of the function it's found in must be compatible with `NULL`.

---

> I understand that in C++, `return NULL;` is the same as `return 0;` in the context of pointers.

Sort of. `NULL` may not be equivalent to `0`, but it will at least convert to something that is.

---

> Obviously for integers, this is not the case as NULL cannot be added, subtracted, etc.

You can perform addition and subtraction to pointers just fine. However, `NULL` must have integral type (4.10/1 and 18.1/4 in C++03) anyway so it's moot. `NULL` may very well be a macro that expands to `0` or `0UL`.

Some modern compilers will at least warn you if it was actually `NULL` you wrote, though.

---

> And that it is encouraged by some to use 0 instead of NULL for pointers because it is more convenient for portability. I'm curious if this is another instance where an equivalence occurs.

No. And I disagree with this advice. Though I can see where it's coming from, since `NULL`'s exact definition varies across implementations, using `NULL` will make it *much* easier to replace with `nullptr` when you switch to C++11, and if nothing else is self-documenting.

Comment: +1 The advice to use `0` instead of `NULL` [comes from Stroustroup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null), but that's not all he said about the issue: he also mentioned using `nullptr` in C++11 :)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive breakdown. I apologize as I had much confused, but your answer really cleared up a lot of things.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not everything Stroustroup says must be correct! Don't forget he's responsible for C++ in the first place :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wish the site had a way to nominate a "comment of the day" :):):)

Comment: `possibly with a void* type` is false. From [4.10p1]: `A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of **integer type** that evaluates to
zero`

Comment: @JesseGood: That doesn't say anything about `NULL`. `NULL` may be equivalent to a null pointer constant or it may simply be convertible to one.

Comment: @JesseGood: Ah, 18.1/4 identifies that `NULL` must _be_ a null pointer constant and that therefore the same must apply for `NULL`. A footnote identifies this exact scenario. Okay then :)

Answer (score 7):

`return` with no expression works only if your function is declared `void`, in a constructor, or in a destructor. If you try to return nothing from a function that returns an `int`, a `double`, etc., your program will not compile:

> error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘int’

According to §6.6.3/2 of C++11:

> A return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4).

(thanks sftrabbit for the excellent comment).

Comment: See §6.6.3/2 of C++11: "A return statement with neither an *expression* nor a *braced-init-list* can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4)."

Comment: Your answer brings up possibly the largest oversight that I made. What would happen if my function was actually returning something? In retrospect, I can't believe that I did account for this scenario. Also sftrabbit, thank your citation.

Answer (score 1):

`return`, `return 0` and `return NULL` are *not* the same.

`return` is only valid with functions returning `void`, e.g.:

```
void func(...);
```

`return 0` is for functions returning some `int` type, e.g.:

```
unsigned long func(...);
```

although it works with floating point types as well:

```
double func(...) { ... return 0; }
```

`return NULL` is for functions returning some `pointer` type, e.g.:

```
Something *func(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like a void function, where the return will simply exit the function and return nothing at all. This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583721/c-return-without-value).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the resulting machine code:

`return` will just put the instruction pointer back to where the caller came from.

`return 0` or `return NULL` will put `0` on the stack, and **then** put the instruction pointer back to where the caller came from. (In C, `NULL` is usually mapped to `0`, although that can (may?) differ in different implementations. In C++, `NULL` is not supposed to be used).

Answer (score 0):

```
const testNullParity = () => {
 return null 
}

const testNullParity2 = () => {
 return 
}


console.log(testNullParity()) //null
console.log(testNullParity2())  //undefined
```

in javascript, return is short for return undefined as null and undefined are two different types, but they are loosely equal ie. testNullParity() == testNullParity2() is true but not testNullParity() === testNullParity2()