# Can a factory method return 0 in case of an error?

Tags: c++, factory

I am studying a bit of code, which contains a factory method, if I am remembering my object orientation correctly.

The factory method and the related classes can be described by the following pseudo-C++.

The class Actor is the base class for the various implementations of concrete actions or operations, which in turn are implemented as derived classes.

The factory method `createActor` receives arguments which are read from an input script, hence prior to calling a constructor some error checking is being done.

I noticed, that in all cases when an error is detected, I find a `return 0` statement.
This can obviously be done, since the code (not written by me) compiles and runs.

However, the factory method is supposed to return a pointer to an Actor-class.
Is in this case `return 0` simply an obscure way to `return NULL`? Maybe I am overthinking this.

```
class Actor
{
  class ActorVariantA : Actor
  {
  }
  // all other ActorVariants are omitted for brevity

  Actor* createActor(arguments)
  {
    if (errorCondition)
      return 0
    if (conditionA)
      return new ActorVariantA(arguments)
  }
}
```

---

I found a somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212901/in-c-is-return-the-same-thing-as-return-null), which in turn led me to [Stroustrup himself](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null).

So, the answer to my question would be: sort-of, but don't do it.

Comment: Instead of `return 0` you should `return nullptr;`  Also since 2011 / c++11 standard  `NULL` should be avoided and `nullptr` should be used instead.

Comment: As you said, it's pseudo-C++, so why do you worry about 0 meaning?

Comment: I am asking about actual C++ code, however, I did not want to copy&paste the actual code, I re-wrote the specific bits I am curious about into my pseudo-C++.

Comment: In real code use `nullptr` like I said in the first comment.

Comment: For a function that returns a pointer, `return 0`, `return NULL` (if a standard header is `#include`d that `#define`s `NULL`), and (C++11 and later) `return nullptr` all cause the function to return a null pointer (a pointer equal to the null pointer constant). In each case, the caller can test if the returned pointer is null, and will have undefined behaviour if a null pointer is dereferenced. If using C++11 and later, `return nullptr` is preferred over the other options since it offers improved safety and less ambiguity in some situations, and less chance of being nagged by other developers.

Comment: In my experience, it's better for a factory function to `throw` an exception if it fails rather than return a `nullptr` (...that being said, use your discretion). Also, the factory function should be `static`, and instead of returning a raw pointer I recommend `std::unique_ptr<Actor>` as the return type.

Comment: Please do your search to related questions **before** you post your own one.

Comment: You could throw an exception instead.

Comment: I am totally confused as to what remains as question after reading https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null !?! Please do not edit answers into the question. If you want to write an answer you can write an answer

Comment: I would also just throw an exception (unless I have hard realtime requirements), it is the least surprising. And ensures you dont have to document a special return cases.

Comment: Interestingly, error handling is done by the caller of the factory method like this: `if(actor_ == 0) errorMessage("Error message");` With `actor_` being of the type `Actor*`. I guess older versions/standards of C++ did not clearly and/or strictly distinguish between a 0-value, a NULL-value and a null-pointer.

Comment: @DohnJoe there is a clear distinction between `0` and `nullptr`. They are off different type, though both can be converted to an `Actor*`

Comment: I guess that's a hold-over from the low-level, when each type, i.e., 0, Null and nullptr, is an all-bits-are-0 type; then one can quite happily interchange them. However, as a casual programmer, I would find more peace of mind, if different things were kept separate, regardless of having the same machine representation. I guess, that's were my confusion came from. The method defines a pointer to a class as return type, yet returns a 0 integer. Valid on a low level, yet somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you are overthinking this. It should really be `return nullptr`, but in this case `return 0` is equivalent.